# Translating into logical expression

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am having difficulty completing the translations.

Translate each of the following statements into a logical expression. Then negate the expression by adding a negation operation to the beginning of the expression. Apply De Morgan's law until each negation operation applies directly to a predicate and then translate the logical expression back into English.\\

This is what I have, but the answers are not showing correctly in PDF. Please advise what I am doing incorrectly.

```
 $\P(X)$          
 $X\D(x)$         
 $x\P(X)\land\D(x)$ item 
 $NEG\FORALLX\(P(X)\Land\D(x))$
 $EXISTX\NEG\P(X)\Land\D(x))$
```

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier to answer this question if you wrote ... well ... the original English phrases that you tried to translate?!

Comment: I've never seen dollar signs being used as symbols in formal logic!

Comment: You have to start from the English statements and then use the logical vocabulary provided: $Px, Dx, \ldots$

Comment: This is what I have to go by    \item $P(x):\; x$ was given the placebo\\\\
  \item $D(x):\; x$ was given the medication\\\\
  \item $M(x): \; x$ had migraines\\\\